# Beckhoff PLCs: Is it possible to download a second runtime without interrupting the first?

Tags: plc

I have a Beckhoff CX5010. I see it is possible to download two project runtimes at the same time and have them run concurrently.

What I want to know is if it's possible to download a single project/program on to a running Beckhoff PLC, where there is already a single runtime running. So essentially I want to be able to go to a site and download my program while the on-site program continues to run. This is if I don't have access to the other program's code.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about industrial automation equipment


Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.  You need to select which runtime you are connected to for download anyway.  Anything which requires a change to your hardware interface connection require a twin cat restart though, which would cause a stop to any run times it is hosting. Also, if your new program has moved variables in the global space around, that can require a realignment with the hardware.

Hope that helps!

glmt